# Facebook login php Auth retornando dialog/oauth?client_id na url

Tags: php, facebook, login, auth

Estou fazendo minha aplicação para *login* no Facebook, porém ele retorna com GET na url `?code=etc...`

Antes estava funcionando normalmente, utilizo via *class* do Facebook. Veja:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET,
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    #$facebook->setAccessToken($_REQUEST['access_token']);
    if($user){
      try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }
```

Para logar estou utilizando a seguinte opção:

```
# There's no active session, let's generate one
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'  => 'email, user_about_me, user_friends, 
                 user_birthday, publish_actions, read_stream, user_website',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/'
));
header("Location: " . $login_url);
```

O problema é que na hora de retornar ele fica atualizando sem parar, pois está retornando pela URL e não via *session*, gostaria de saber como faço para voltar a retornar via *session*?

**@EDIÇÃO@**

Arquivos que estou utilizando:

Arquivo de configuração (config.php):

```
define('APP_ID', '42826xxxxxx0624');
define('APP_SECRET', 'fd14bxxxxx04a1fbc');
```

Arquivo onde redireciona facebook (Login.php):

```
<?php
    include("functions.php");
    include("config.class.php");
    include("config.php");
    include("modules/Facebook/facebook.php");
    if(@$atual[0]=="facebook"){
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId' => APP_ID,
                    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
                    'cookie'    => TRUE, /* Optional */
                    'oath'      => TRUE  /* Optional */
                    ));

        $access_token   =   $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $user           =   $facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
          try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
          }
            if (!empty($user_profile)){
                # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
                $name           = $user_profile['name'];
                $uid            = $user_profile['id'];
                $email          = $user_profile['email'];
                $gender         = $user_profile['gender'];
                $birthday       = $user_profile['birthday'];
                $link           = $user_profile['link'];

                $user = new User();
                if(!$user->checkUserFacebook($uid, $username, $email)){
                    echo '
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <form action="javascript:func()" name="facebookLogin" id="facebookLogin" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login com Facebook</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                                <div class="alertLogin"></div>
                                <p class="text-info" id="inputType-name">Nome:  <br>
                                <input class="span6" id="name" type="text" value="'.$name.'" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" 
                    ';
                    if($name){echo ' disabled ';}
                    echo '
                                ></p>
                                <p class="text-info" id="inputType-cpf">CPF:<br>
                                <input class="span6" id="cpf" name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu CPF"></p>
                                <p class="text-info" id="inputType-email">E-mail:<br>
                                <input class="span6" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="'.$email.'" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" 
                    ';
                                if($email){echo ' disabled ';}
                    echo '
                                ></p>
                                <p class="text-info" id="inputType-phone">Telefone para contato (Somente mostrado caso for ganhador de RIFAS):<br>
                                <input class="span6" id="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu Telefone"></p>
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$uid.'" name="uid" id="uid">
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$gender.'" name="gender" id="gender">
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$birthday.'" name="birthday" id="birthday">
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$link.'" name="link" id="link">
                                <p class="text-info"><input type="checkbox" value="aceitou"> Você aceita nossos termos de uso?</p>
                            </p>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-rifao" type="submit">Salvar e logar</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    ';
                }else{
                    $_SESSION["type"]   =   "facebook";
                    $_SESSION["uid"]    =   $uid;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                die("There was an error.");
            }
        } else {
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'=>'email, user_about_me, user_friends, user_birthday, publish_actions, read_stream, user_website',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/'
            ));
            header("Location: " . $login_url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Será que é na API mesmo ou no seu PHP? `$login_url` é o mesmo que `http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/`? Talvez não será um problema nisto `header("Location: " . $login_url);`? O script de login está na URL `http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/`? Por que se for isto, explicaria o loop

Comment: http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/ onde está script para logar no facebook, ele acessa via url amigável.

Comment: Isso não responde as minhas perguntas, ao menos não de forma clara, poderia tentar ser mais claro? Vou perguntar de novo: `$login_url` é o mesmo que `http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/`?  O script de login está na URL `http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/`?

Comment: Este erro normalmente é por conta do link que está lá no APP não ser o mesmo do `$login_url`

Comment: Um exemplo simples de debug :) troque o `header("Location: " . $login_url);` por `echo $login_url;` e veja o que retorna, se retornar a mesma url é porque está em loop (ou direcionando para outra que causa o loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1 -** Verifique se o seu APP, no facebook, está **PUBLICADO**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2 -** Veja se as permissões estão habilitadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3 -** Gere uma nova App Secret e substitua a anterior.

**4 -** O mais importante, veja se a url, que está na api, é a mesma que contém o `fbconnect.php`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**5 -** O básico para se obter os dados:

```
<?php

global $user;
$user = $_SESSION['sessao_logado']; 

if(!isset($user)) // Verificando se há login
{

    //Configurações
    $app_id     = "42826xxxxxx0624";
    $app_secret = "fd14bxxxxx04a1fbc";
    $site_url   = "http://www.rifao.com.br/facebook/";

    try{
        include_once "src/facebook.php";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
    // Criando instância da aplicação
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $app_id,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        ));

    // Obtendo o User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user){
        // Obtendo logout URL
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    }else{
        // Obtendo login URL
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope'         => 'public_profile, email, user_friends',
            'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
            ));
    }

    if($user){


        try{

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $name = $user_profile['name'];
        $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $gender = $user_profile['gender'];
        $id = $user_profile['uid_facebook'];

        //AQUI VOCÊ JÁ PODE LOGAR O CLIENTE COM OS DADOS ACIMA
    }

        catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                error_log($e);
                $user = NULL;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Lollipop, muito obrigado por responder!, infelizmente não deu certo, então postei os arquivos utilizados, seria possível dar uma olhadinha para ver se está correto? MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Deu certo, @LeonardoJoksan?

Comment: infelizmente não, não sei mais o que fazer. Difícil...

Comment: Estou estudando sim, obrigado mesmo.